# Random Join in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have two table that called Product and ProductImage.

There is 1-n relation between two table. One product and more than one image depending on the product.

I want to create a product view and I want to get one image randomly from ProductImage table for each product.

Example Data : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/43c69

I want something like below.

```
+-----------+------+-------------+
| ProductId | Name |   WebPath   |
+-----------+------+-------------+
|         1 | Foo  | foowebpath2 |
|         2 | Boo  | boowebpath3 |
|         3 | Zoo  | zoowebpath1 |
+-----------+------+-------------+
```

or

```
+-----------+------+-------------+
| ProductId | Name |   WebPath   |
+-----------+------+-------------+
|         1 | Foo  | foowebpath1 |
|         2 | Boo  | boowebpath1 |
|         3 | Zoo  | zoowebpath6 |
+-----------+------+-------------+
```

or

```
+-----------+------+-------------+
| ProductId | Name |   WebPath   |
+-----------+------+-------------+
|         1 | Foo  | foowebpath4 |
|         2 | Boo  | boowebpath2 |
|         3 | Zoo  | zoowebpath5 |
+-----------+------+-------------+
```

or etc...

It have to be different each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this

```
SELECT *, (SELECT TOP 1 WebPath FROM ProductImage PI 
WHERE PI.ProductId = P.ProductId order by NEWID()  ) as WebPart from Product P
```

Check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/43c69/16

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH Image AS
(
  SELECT *, RAND(ProductImageId) R
  FROM ProductImage 
)

SELECT p.*, i2.* FROM Product P
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT ProductId, MIN(R) R
     FROM Image
     GROUP BY ProductId) i1 ON i1.ProductId = p.ProductId
INNER JOIN Image i2 ON i2.R = i1.R
```